# How to capture ALT+N on keypress in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, keyboard-shortcuts, keypress

I have some simple code which logs the pressed key code, like this:

```js
window.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
  console.log(e.keyCode);
})
```

It seems to work for <kbd>Alt</kbd> + pretty much every other on my keyboard. *Except for <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>.*
It seems to not be registering the event at all! Just <kbd>N</kbd> (without the <kbd>Alt</kbd>) seems to work, and so do other combinations like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>. When I type <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> nothing else happens, so it's not been reserved by the system as far as I know. I am using Chrome on a Mac.

Is this just something wrong with my computer or does it happen for others too? If it does happen for others, why does it do this and are there ways to detect it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try :

```js
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.altKey == true && e.keyCode == 78)
    console.log('Alt + N'); 
});
```

Comment: Note you don't need a separate variable for alt detection the `event` object has an [`altKey` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/altKey) which is true when alt is being held

Comment: @PatrickEvans Thanks for the links, I never noticed that property. I read the documentation on `keypress` and found the reason why `keypress` doesn't work with modifier keys. I have updated my answer with the excerpts from the documentation. @Ashraf I feel you should include this in your answer for the sake of completeness to the OP's question.

Comment: this works for mac and windows? thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Crashalot Yes .

Answer (score 3):

Using `keypress` event doesn't work for me for <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> and for any combination with <kbd>Alt</kbd> for that matter. Some combinations are working with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and some aren't.

However, when I listen for `keydown` and `keyup` events, I am able to log these events. So, I guess you could listen for `keydown` event on <kbd>Alt</kbd> and if there is a `keydown` event for <kbd>N</kbd> before <kbd>Alt</kbd> generates `keyup`, you have successfully detected a <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> combo.

<strike>I am not sure about why this happens though.</strike>

**EDIT**

According to [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress),

> The keypress event is fired when a key that produces a character value is pressed down. Examples of keys that produce a character value are alphabetic, numeric, and punctuation keys.
>
> Examples of **keys that don't produce a character value** are modifier keys such as **Alt, Shift, Ctrl, or Meta**.

As for why some shortcuts work in Chrome, while some do not, [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress#Notes) says

> Chrome does not fire the keypress event for **known** keyboard shortcuts. **Which keyboard shortcuts are known depends on the user's system**. Use the keydown event to implement keyboard shortcuts.